# Splitting 7 different columns into 5 different ranges in R

Tags: r

I would like to know how to divide the seven different columns to 5 different ranges/level. Each level has a certain range. Following is the data.

```
Name    V1.1    V1.2    V2.1    V2.2    V3.1    V3.2
Arn     Eng     80      Sci      50     Mat      17
Brn     Sci     90      Eng      60     Mat      28
Crn     Mat     100     Sci      47     Eng      27.
```

The five bucket ranges are as follows.
<=20 Level1, <=40 Level2, <=60 Level3, <=80 Level4, Level5

Expected output:

```
Name Level1   Level2   Level3   Level4  Level5
Arn  Mat      NA        Sci      Eng     NA
Brn  NA       Mat       Eng      NA      Sci
Crn  NA       Eng       Sci      NA      Mat
```

Comment: We can use `cut` i.e. `cut(unlist(df1[c(3,5,7)]), breaks=c(-Inf, 20, 40, 60, 80, Inf), labels= paste0("Level", 1:5))`

Comment: You're going to have an easier time working with this data if you organize it into three columns: something like Name, Subject, Score, and Version, where Subject is one of Eng, Sci, Mat, Score is one of those 80/90/etc columns, and Version is V1, V2, or V3. This will let you work with all the numeric values in the same column.

Comment: For example, after loading the dplyr and tidyr packages you could rearrange this data into this format using `dat2 <- dat %>% gather(col, val, -Name) %>% separate(col, c("Version", "col"), convert = TRUE) %>% mutate(col = c("Subject", "Score")[col]) %>% spread(col, val) %>% mutate(Score = as.numeric(Score))`

Comment: It is not clear about the rules of having NAs in the expected output

Comment: NA implies that neither of their marks fall in to that level

Comment: Please check the updated solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cut` to create the different "Level"s based on the numeric columns in the dataset.  We loop through the numeric columns with `lapply`, use `cut` with `breaks` mentioned as in the OP's post, and `labels` for specifying the "Level"s.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df2)`), `melt` to 'long' format and then `dcast` to 'wide' format.

```
df2 <- df1
df2[c(3,5,7)] <- lapply(df1[c(3,5,7)], function(x) 
     cut(x, breaks=c(-Inf, 20, 40, 60, 80, Inf),
     labels= paste0("Level", 1:5)))
library(data.table)
dM <- melt(setDT(df2), measure = list(seq(2,ncol(df2),
                   by =2), seq(3, ncol(df2), by = 2)))
dcast(dM, Name~value2, value.var='value1')
#   Name Level1 Level2 Level3 Level4 Level5
#1:  Arn    Mat     NA    Sci    Eng     NA
#2:  Brn     NA    Mat    Eng     NA    Sci
#3:  Crn     NA    Eng    Sci     NA    Mat
```

This is the OP's expected output

```
# Name Level1   Level2   Level3   Level4  Level5
# Arn  Mat      NA        Sci      Eng     NA
# Brn  NA       Mat       Eng      NA      Sci
# Crn  NA       Eng       Sci      NA      Mat
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Arn", "Brn", "Crn"),
V1.1 = c("Eng", 
"Sci", "Mat"), V1.2 = c(80L, 90L, 100L), V2.1 = c("Sci", "Eng", 
"Sci"), V2.2 = c(50L, 60L, 47L), V3.1 = c("Mat", "Mat", "Eng"
 ), V3.2 = c(17L, 28L, 27L)), .Names = c("Name", "V1.1", "V1.2", 
"V2.1", "V2.2", "V3.1", "V3.2"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: @Ram because you didn't show the expected output earlier

Comment: I understand. Could you please guide for the expected output

Comment: The above solution is not dividing into levels, Instead showing all the marks as the column headers

Comment: @Ram It is the same as the expected output you showed in your post.

Comment: @Ram I don't find any difference between your expected output and mine.

Comment: @Ram I pasted your expected output below the `dcast` output.  Please tell me where there is difference???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105987/discussion-between-ram-and-akrun).

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Name' not found

Comment: @Ram I am not sure what is the problem iin your end.  Updated with the data I used.